# How to set chart title as a selected column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, title

New to VBA and not sure how to set the Chart title to a specific selected column. I am creating multiple graphs from one data sheet so want to be able to select the data and the graph to be named appropriately.

```
Sub Charter()

    Dim my_range    As Range

    Set my_range = Selection
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=my_range

    Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

I want the graph title to use the data set name that is used in 
`ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlXYScatter`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text` is the property needed for the text. This is a way to refer it in the `ActiveChart`:

```
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Text
```

If the name of the `FullSeriesCollection(1)` is to be used, then:

```
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name
```

(in general, avoid working with `Select` and `ActiveChart` in VBA - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba))

Comment: thank you, but do you know how to set it so that the chart title is taken from the data used in `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlXYScatter`

Comment: @ZacEpstein - I miss what you mean by "the data used in `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlXYScatter` `xlXYScatter` is the ChartType of the collection, it is no data.

Comment: I want the chart title to be the third column of data that I select, the same data that is used in the scatterplot name from the chart legend

Comment: I want it to have the same name as series 2 from the legend

Comment: @Zacchini - `ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name` this should work